# WCF There was no endpoint listening at net.pipe://localhost/Ivan.WCFService.Lib/Service1 that could accept the message

Tags: c#, wcf

I host a WCF service in windows service to achieve cross process access on the Same computer.
Thus, netNamedPipBinding is adopted.
Now, everything works properly in my develop PC(client could access wcf service by endpoint).
But when i copy the client.exe, host.exe, and wcf.dll to another PC for test. It cannot work and throw such exception:

```
System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at net.pipe://localhost/Ivan.WCFService.Lib/MyService that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details. ---> System.IO.PipeException: The pipe endpoint 'net.pipe://localhost/Ivan.WCFService.Lib/MyService' could not be found on your local machine.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace:
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.PipeConnectionInitiator.GetPipeName(Uri uri, IPipeTransportFactorySettings transportFactorySettings)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.NamedPipeConnectionPoolRegistry.NamedPipeConnectionPool.GetPoolKey(EndpointAddress address, Uri via)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationPool`2.TakeConnection(EndpointAddress address, Uri via, TimeSpan timeout, TKey& key)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper.EstablishConnection(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOpenOnce.System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ICallOnce.Call(ServiceChannel channel, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EnsureOpened(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]:
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Ivan.WCFService.Client.MyServiceReference.IMyService.QueryLinks()
   at Ivan.WCFService.Client.MyServiceReference.MyServiceClient.QueryLinks() in line 2547
```

So here are the questions:

1. Is there any files missed to be copied.
2. The exception points to the endpoint. Here are my wcf service lib config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Ivan.WCFService.Lib.MyService">
        <endpoint address="MyService" binding="netNamedPipeBinding" contract="Ivan.WCFService.Lib.IMyService"/>
        <endpoint address="MyService/mex" binding="mexNamedPipeBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.pipe://localhost/Ivan.WCFService.Lib"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="False" httpsGetEnabled="False"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1"/></startup></configuration>
```

I'm not sure whether the baseAddress should be set by "localhost" in my case.
And also post the client config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
    <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value=""/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
    <membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri=""/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="ClientRoleProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientRoleProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" cacheTimeout="86400"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <netNamedPipeBinding>
              <binding name="NetNamedPipeBinding_IMyService" >
                <security mode="Transport">
                  <transport protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
                </security>
              </binding>
            </netNamedPipeBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="net.pipe://localhost/Ivan.WCFService.Lib/MyService"
                binding="netNamedPipeBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetNamedPipeBinding_IMyService"
                contract="MyServiceReference.IMyService" name="NetNamedPipeBinding_IMyService">
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1"/></startup></configuration>
```

3. Will Win10 platform security factor influence such end point?(Already run as administrator)
4. Already enable net.pip Listener Adapter service, and its status is running now.
   In conclusion, the pair of config file could run properly in my dev PC. When i try to test it in other PC, it throw no endpoint exception. Could any one help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify baseAddress:

```
           <endpoint address="net.pipe://The IP address of the WCF server/Ivan.WCFService.Lib/MyService"
                binding="netNamedPipeBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetNamedPipeBinding_IMyService"
                contract="MyServiceReference.IMyService" name="NetNamedPipeBinding_IMyService">
            </endpoint>
```

If the client and server are on the same machine, we can use localhost. If the client and server are not on the same machine, we need to modify the client's endpoint address. If the client's access endpoint address is still localhost at this time Will report an error.

**You need to modify the endpoint address of the client to make it the same as the IP address of the WCF server, and then recompile.**

Comment: I do use both client and server on the same machine. And currently, both address in client and server is set to localhost as shown in the original post. Under such setting, it could work properly in the developing machine. However, once i run it in other PC, it throws exception.

Comment: To run on a different machine, please modify the endpoint address.

Comment: The client needs to access the WCF server-side through the endpoint address.

Comment: So, i suspect that is there any steps i missed to implement if i wanna test both client and server to a different machine. Currently, i just copy all related files to PC and then register the windows service(wcf service host).

Comment: Do you mean that the client-side and server-side are copied to the same machine at the same time?

Comment: Let's say that in the develop machine(PC1), i have a pair of server1 and client1. I cope all files to another PC2, then i have server 2 and client2. All i need, is client 1 access server 1, and client 2 access server 2. Under such background, do i still need modify endpoint address？ From my understanding, i think you are suggesting keep the endpoint address of the pair of client and server consistent? Am i misunderstand?

Comment: All the relation expected to happen is in the same machine. And in PC1, client could access server properly, while in PC2, it could not work.

Comment: If all tests occur on the same machine, no modification is required. I suspect that you may have used an IP address or machine name in the endpoint address.

Comment: If you want to migrate to PC2, you can try to modify the client's endpoint address to PC2's IP address.

Comment: The test machine config is the same as i posted. For server , it is <add baseAddress="net.pipe://localhost/Ivan.WCFService.Lib"/>. For client it is, <endpoint address="net.pipe://localhost/Ivan.WCFService.Lib/MyService".  The same config, could run in PC1, but cannot run properly in PC2.

Comment: Can the service be found through the address of net.pipe://localhost/Ivan.WCFService.Lib/MyService in PC2?

Comment: It is also possible that the service did not run successfully.

Comment: No, it said cannot found:The pipe endpoint 'net.pipe://localhost/Ivan.WCFService.Lib/MyService' could not be found on your local machine.

Comment: Then this should be a service problem, the service is not running in PC2.

Comment: I can understand that client have to know which address is server at, then it could access server. But in this case, i did not modify any config when moving files from PC1 to PC2.

Comment: Do you mean WCF service or the host windows service?

Comment: I think the WCF service is not running, and the exception throws when the instance is attempted to be created. But i have no idea about how to fix it...

Comment: It is still not sure whether it is a problem with the WCF service or a computer. You can download the template project in this link for testing: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/netnamedpipebinding